# typo3: aggegrate content from other pages

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to create a page in which I include content of other pages, using their ID.
Do I have to create a new template for this page?

My main template is a one column template.

For example, I have `content1` on page 1, `content2` on page 2 and `content3` on page 3.

I want to have to have `content1` `content2` `content3` on page 4. Pages are not on the same level.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the content element "Insert Records", it lets you display records from other pages, not limited to content elements. These records need a rendering definition, which is already there for content elements.

Comment: The "Insert records" element is a manual element and if I add records to my pages, I will have to add them also in my "insert records" list. Do you know if there is a way in TS to include all records of X pages easily?

Comment: Yes, you can use a [CONTENT](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html) content element from TypoScript, with the `select.where` or `select.andWhere` property set to something like `pid IN (1,17,42,4711)`.

Comment: Is this a good start?
   `1 = CONTENT`
    `1.table = tt_content`
    `1.select.where =  pid IN (71,75)`
How can I display the content in the border part?

Comment: Just assign the to a marker or variable, and use it in the template... If you assign an empty string to that marker or variable on "normal" pages, a single template file might suffice.